# Zoom the image inside iframe by default

Tags: html, iframe

I have an image inside iframe. Document onload, the image seems to be in default state which is not helping to read the content in the image. 
All need is to Zoom the image by default. Now, it is happening when we click on the image. But I need this to happen without clicking on the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<iframe src="http://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/Templates/2.0/images/pp-content-img-sample1.png" style="max-width:950px; width:100%;" >
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh.. the image you have saved in that iframe is 527 pixels width by 316 pixels height. The image is showing correctly. You can't read the image text because the image is too small. You will need to save it to be a larger size.

My suggestion would be to take your text out of the image and make it part of your website. If you cant do that there are tuturial on how to properly save images for the web. Example: [Like this](http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/comprehensive-guide-saving-images-for-web/)